# Jquery hover stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have a slideshow on my ipb board, and like to stop it when hovered.

I found this code, and really like to add some code in it to stop.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var JQry = jQuery.noConflict(); 
JQry(document).ready(function(){
    JQry('.slideshow_{$slideshow['ssid']}').show().bxSlider({
        captions: true,
        controls: false,
        mode: '{$slideshow['slideshow_style']}',
        slideMargin: 5,
        minSlides: <if test="$slideshow['slideshow_style']=='vertical'">{$slideshow['slideshow_minSlides']}<else />{$slideshow['slideshow_minSlides']}</if>,
        maxSlides: {$slideshow['slideshow_maxSlides']},
        slideWidth: <if test="$slideshow['slideshow_img_w'] && $slideshow['slideshow_img_w'] > 0">{$slideshow['slideshow_img_w']}<else />{$this->settings['bim_fcontent_thumb_width']}</if>,
        slideHeight: <if test="$slideshow['slideshow_img_h'] && $slideshow['slideshow_img_h'] > 0">{$slideshow['slideshow_img_h']}<else />{$this->settings['bim_fcontent_thumb_height']}</if>,          
        auto: <if test="$slideshow['slideshow_autoplay']=='1'">true<else />false</if>,
        autoHover: true,
        speed: {$slideshow['slideshow_speed']},         
        pause: {$slideshow['slideshow_duration']},
        pager: <if test="$slideshow['slideshow_shownav']=='1'">true<else />false</if>,
        preloadImages: 'all',
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle of the code. According to the documentation on  bxslider (http://bxslider.com/options) autoHover:true should make it stop on hover.

Comment: read the documentation...... hmmmm. It's from an add-on from IPB, just try to make it work as i want it.

The autohover isn't stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

Also add hover event to your code:

```
JQry('.slideshow_{$slideshow['ssid']}').show().bxSlider({
    hover: return,
});
```

When you hover on the image, the hover event is fired, and as we wrote return statement function will be exited.